Fitnesse acceptance testing
I am new to fitnesse framework
I have already fitnesseroot folder inside my spring module
But when I am starting fitnesse server it have created new fitnesseroot folder outside the module, and fitnesse taking the new module instead of already available one
So can't able to see the testsuite pages
I have checked,but I can't find any lead to this issue

This question is a bit too vague. Can you elaborate on how the project is set up (are you using maven or gradle, or ..., what does the project configuration look like, how do you start the server)?

We are using maven as a project build tool. It's a multi module project one of the module is fitnesse acceptance test module. Inside the fitnesse module I have already one fitnesseroot folder,it have suitetest pages. But while running fitnesse server it creating new fitnesseroot folder root level . And it's not pointing to existing one inside module. Where to change the path to fetch the existing root folder.

The command line options for FitNesse are documented at https://fitnesse.org/FitNesse/UserGuide/AdministeringFitNesse/CommandLineArguments.html. It sounds like you want to pass a -r value. So But how to pass value depends on how FitNesse is started, that is probably configured in your project's pom.xml somewhere

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
